# How come the table head column and row not expanding to 2?

Tags: html

Why my table head column and row is not expanding into two. I was wondering if anyone could help. Below is the screenshot of my code.

[image]

Comment: I tried to edit your post as much as I could. please try to explain a little bit more and provide some background on what tool/language you are using and what are you trying to do. Use appropriate tags as well. Read this link before posting a question here- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Post your actual code here, not an image of your code.  Try to create a [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)